# Why I can't directly assign null to a number attribute, but I can if it's a result of an if statement?

Tags: typescript

Why TypeScript has no problem with me doing this:

```
return {
 Price: value.rawPrice === null ? null : value.rawPrice
}
```

but has issues with me doing this:

```
return {
 Price: null
}
```

Where field `Price`is of type number

Comment: I can't replicate this behavior. Tested in the TS [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) in a function with the return type `{ Price: number }`. Your second case doesn't yield an error for me. What is the specific error you're getting, and what version of TS are you using?

Comment: Oh, I'm guessing you're running the compiler with the `--strictNullChecks` flag?

Comment: Same as @pushkin; additionally, if I turn on "strictNullChecks", both of those examples show a compile error (awful formatting due to length of URL): http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Pricey%20%7B%20Price%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Whatever%20%7B%20getPrice(value%3A%20Pricey)%3A%20Pricey%20%7B%20return%20%7B%20Price%3A%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20null%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20value.Price%20%7D%3B%20%7D%20makePrice()%3A%20Pricey%20%7B%20return%20%7B%20Price%3A%20null%20%7D%3B%20%7D%7D

Comment: ok yes its the bloody flag, thank you @pushkin

Comment: Like @MikeMcCaughan said, I get an error in both cases when using that flag. I'm curious why you don't. Maybe this is an old `tsc` bug? Are you on the latest version?

Comment: how do I check that?

Comment: `tsc --version`

Comment: I'm on windows so this doesn't do anything

Comment: @LucasSeveryn You mean it's not in your %PATH%? Find where `tsc` is installed and run the command from that directory.

Comment: probably because it can't explicitly cast it.  `Price:null as number` might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of `--strictNullChecks` in the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

Use **undefined** instead of **null**

[here a working example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Pricey%20%7B%20Price%3A%20number%3B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Whatever%20%7B%20getPrice(value%3A%20Pricey)%3A%20Pricey%20%7B%20return%20%7B%20Price%3A%20value%20%3D%3D%3D%20null%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20value.Price%20%7D%3B%20%7D%20makePrice()%3A%20Pricey%20%7B%20return%20%7B%20Price%3A%20null%20%7D%3B%20%7D%7D)